# KeyError when reading CSV in chunks with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I've a 12 million rows and 9 cols CSV file.

> I'm getting a `Keyword` error not a `MemoryError`, not a duplicated
>   question.

I need to read it get `2nd lowest rate` for each `zipcode`.

I've read that to work with big datasets from CSV files, you need to read them in chunks and apply your code to each chunk.

I've this:

```
import pandas as pd
import csv


for df in pd.read_csv('slcsp/new_df.csv', sep='\t', iterator=True, chunksize=1000):
        df.groupby('zipcode').rate.nsmallest(2).reset_index().drop('level_1',1) \
        .drop_duplicates(subset=['zipcode'], keep='last')
```

But getting error:

**KeyError: 'zipcode'** #but there is a column called `zipcode`

I've checked and there is a column named `zipcode`.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "slcsp/slcsp.py", line 19, in <module>
    df.loc[df.groupby('zipcode').rate.rank(method='first').eq(2),['zipcode','rate']]
  File "D:\virtual_envs\web_scrapping\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 7632, in groupby
    observed=observed, **kwargs)
  File "D:\virtual_envs\web_scrapping\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py", line 2110, in groupby
    return klass(obj, by, **kwds)
  File "D:\virtual_envs\web_scrapping\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py", line 360, in __init__
    mutated=self.mutated)
  File "D:\virtual_envs\web_scrapping\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\grouper.py", line 578, in _get_grouper
    raise KeyError(gpr)
KeyError: 'zipcode'
```

Comment: how to do it right?

Comment: It is not a MemoryError but a Keyword error. Not duplicated.